# Three white queens, two white knights, and one rook on a chess board

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, chess, optimization

On an  8 x 8 chessboard, place three white queens, two white knights, and one white rook so that every cell of the board is under attack by at least one piece not standing on it.

Source: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/048684241X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048684241X)

Comment: Oh wow, you've written a puzzle book! Kudos!

Answer (score 4):

I used integer linear programming (and, sorry, a computer):

> \begin{matrix}&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&N&.&N&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&Q&.&Q&.&Q&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&R\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\\end{matrix}

The solution is unique up to rotation and reflection.